# javascript validate birthday

Tags: javascript, validation

im trying to validate birth numbers with a simple script but this script returns true even tho i type in a month over 12 and day over 31, so what have i missed?

```
var as = /^[0-9]{6}[-+][0-9]{4}$/;
var pn=document.forms.kontakt.pnr.value;
if (as.test(pn)) {
  var year = pn.substr(0,2);
  var month = pn.substr(2,2);
  var day = pn.substr(4,2);
  if (month <= 13 && day <= 32) {
    return true;
  }
} else {
  alert ("Fyll i korrekt personnummer xxxxxx-xxxx");
  kontakt.pnr.style.background = "red";
  return false;
}
```

Comment: You are probably misunderstanding the use of `<=`. What you need is `<`.

Comment: just note that even when it works it wont check if the date is really valid in time

Comment: @RahulDesai even if i make it without the < it still does the same thing :(

Comment: @CodeiSir yes i know, just a simple validation since its my 2nd script im doing hah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The if/else statement is fine, the problem is probably in your substr or regex. 
I would console.log your "month" and "day" variables to narrow down your bug.

Answer (score 0):

```
var as = /^[0-9]{6}-[0-9]{4}$/;
var pn = document.forms.kontakt.pnr.value; 
if (as.test(pn)) {
var year  = pn.substr(0,2);
var month = pn.substr(2,2);
var day   = pn.substr(4,2);
if (month > 12 || day > 31) {
alert("Fyll i korrekt personnummer");  siffror
kontakt.pnr.style.background = "red";
return false;
}
else {
return true;
 } 
 } 
 else {
alert("Fyll i personnummer i formatet xxxxxx-xxxx");
kontakt.pnr.style.background = "red";
return false;
 }
```

This was the solution for me!